# Update queryset with dictionary values

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I am writing custom List filter and inside filter call i have a **Django queryset** as below

**queryset =[qs1, qs2, qs3]**

queryset have a attribute **Count_val = 0,  UUID = (unique id)** for all objects in queryset

so lets say

qs1 = {uuid: 123, count_val: 0}

qs2 = {uuid: 456, count_val: 0}

qs1 = {uuid: 789, count_val: 0}

Also

I have a **dictionary like  {uuid: count_val}**

example {123: 5,  456: 10 , 789: 15 }

I want to update queryset attribute count_values for all objects before returning queryset as response

Maybe  annotate but how i pull each uuid for each value

```
queryset=queryset.annotate(count_val = Case(When(uuid_in=dictionary.keys(), then=dictionary[uuid]), field_type=Integer))   ## not correct syntax just an example
# inserting to new field is also fine
#queryset.extra(value={count_val : dictionary[uuid]})
return queryset
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Where did you get the dictionary from? If from another query you should be able to do this with some annotation. If not you will have to do some ugly chained annotation

Comment: its not from query

Comment: Can you give me an example for annotation by which i can update uuid or new field with respect to dictionary

Comment: added an example annotation as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a list of `When` objects that match each key in the dictionary and return the value. Then unpack this list into positional arguments to the `Case` object

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

whens = [When(uuid=k, then=Value(v)) for k, v in dictionary.items()]
queryset = queryset.annotate(count_val=Case(*whens, output_field=IntegerField(), default=Value(0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the query set be `qs` and dictionary be `d`

```
qs2=qs[:]
for elem in qs2:
    qs2["count_val"] = d[elem["uuid"]]
return qs2
```

Comment: qs["count"] gives me TypeError <Model Name>  is not subscriptable

Comment: It should be elem.count_val= d[elem["uuid"]]

Comment: Yes same my bad i have done same but not working (typo in above) i tried  element.uuid only

Comment: It seems its updating inside CustomFilter but after returning to AdminManager its calling another method for uuid field   def get_uuid(obj): return obj.uuid

Comment: Here uuid has old values instead of updated one. But quere length is correct (i am changing it)

Comment: Can i do annotation to update uuid with respect to dictionary ?